# Customizing the scroll bar

Tags: html, scrollbar, styling

Can we change the appearance of scroll bar? I mean we want to change the image of the scroll bar, so it can match our web theme. more specifically, i'm pointing at the scroll bar in

```
<div style=overflow:auto>
```

If it can't be done, then is there some other way to make our own "scroll bar", which use our own image?

Perhaps if we're insane enough, maybe we'll do it like this.
We make a bunch of `<div>` which contain an image of up arrow, scroll, down arrow, etc. And then we applied some function to each of them. off course the width of scroll will depend on the amount of the content.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this site](http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar) - I've heard good things about the method implemented, although I have never really bothered to create my own custom scroll bars.

You should be able to style in line with your own theme with a bit of experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of custom scrollbar available in the jQuery plugin here is some 
http://designhuntr.com/custom-jquery-scrollers/

I would suggest http://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/